# Passing data between tabbed views in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project that has a tabbed bar controller that is linked to a FirstViewController.swfit and a SecondViewController.swift.

I have a textbox in the first view, and in the second view I have a label and a button. I want the user to be able to type something in the textbox in the first view, then switch over to the second tab, and press the button and have whatever they typed in the textbox appear in the label.

I have tried researching all over the place and I came across segues and singletons, but I am not sure how to exactly apply those or if they are even necessary for what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you!

EDIT

My SecondViewController.swift code based on razor's reply:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var firstViewController: FirstViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let fvc = firstViewController {
        self.label.text = fvc.textbox.text
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is for SecondViewController to have a reference to FirstViewcontroller.  So within the ViewController class, you'd have e.g. an optional variable like:

`var firstViewController: FirstViewController?`

Then, when you handle the button press, you can do something like

```
if let fvc = firstViewController {
  self.label.text = fvc.textbox.text
}
```

Comment: Except that having one view controller manipulate another view controllers views is very bad practice. you should create a String property in fvc and read that rather than attempting to read the other VC's text box contents.

Comment: I added these to my SecondViewController.swift but it does not work. I edited the OP to include the code. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @pozufu you need to set firstViewController to actually point to the instance of the FirstViewController.  Depending on how you are instantiating FirstViewController, you could do that e.g. in prepareForSegue.  But when SecondViewController is initialized from FirstViewController, do something like secondViewController.firstViewController = self

Comment: @razor I am fairly new to swift so sorry for the ignorance, but how exactly would I point the firstViewController variable to the instance of the FirstViewController?

Comment: How is the SecondViewController being instantiated?  If you are using a storyboard, there is probably a segue. Can you post the code for FirstViewController?